# How to fix a KeyError in django?

Tags: python, django, view, dictionary

`print user_dic[id]` displays the right result `PersonA`. This is when I input the id manually.

```
user_stream = {u'2331449': u'PersonB', u'17800013': u'PersonA'}
user_dic= {}
for item in user_stream:
    user_dic[item['id']] = item['name']

id = '17800013'
print user_dic[id]  #returns the right value
```

However, when I try to put the `user_id` through a for loop that iterates through json I get an error: `KeyError at 17800013` for the line `name = user_dic[user_id]`. I don't understand why the `user_dic[id]` works when manually inputting the id, but `user_dic[user_id]` doesn't work when going through the for loop even though the input is the same.

```
#right fql query
fql_query = "SELECT created_time, post_id, actor_id, type, updated_time, attachment FROM stream WHERE post_id in (select post_id from stream where ('video') in attachment AND source_id IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) limit 100)"
fql_var = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?access_token=" + token['access_token'] + "&query=" + fql_query + "&format=json"
data = urllib.urlopen(fql_var)
fb_stream = json.loads(data.read())

fb_feed = []
for post in fb_stream:
    user_id = post["actor_id"]
    name = user_dic[user_id]  #this is the line giving me trouble
    title = post["attachment"]["name"]
    link = post["attachment"]["href"]
    video_id = link[link.find('v=')+2 : link.find('v=')+13]
    fb_feed.append([user_id, name, title, video_id])
```

Comment: May be the `actor_id` is not same as `user_id`? Try to print `user_dic` and then `actor_id` and check manually is it there or not

Comment: When I put print user_id, I get 17800013 which is what I manually inputted in the first part of the code.  IS that what you were asking?

Comment: Check my answer i have updated it

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `user_dic`. What you are doing in first part is just a redundant work and you are also doing it wrong. Your `user_stream` is already in a form how you wanted it. Your first part should contain this line:

```
user_stream = {u'2331449': u'PersonB', u'17800013': u'PersonA'}
```

And in second part (at line where you are facing problem) you should do:

```
name = user_stream[user_id]
```

If you think that you will face `KeyError` then `dict` has a method `.get`, which returns `None` if the Key is not found. You can specify your value instead of `None` to return if there is `KeyError`

```
name = user_stream.get('user_id')
#returns None by default
name = user_stream.get('user_id', '')
#returns empty string now
#on both cases exception will not raised
```

Comment: When I use name = user_stream[user_id], I get IndexError: list  index out of range. I have print user_id before this line and it prints the user_id...I've confirmed that this user_id does exist in user_stream as well.

Comment: As far as i know looking on your code `user_stream` is a `dict` not a `list`. The `IndexError` is for `lists`. May be you are overwriting `user_stream` variable some where. Please share a link of your full code, use pastebin.

Comment: print the value of `user_stream` after this line `user_stream = json.loads(u.read().decode("utf-8"))["data"]`.

Comment: it returns the json of friends: [{'name': 'Samir Rao', 'id': '13596'}, {'name': 'Tom Wionzek', 'id': '15226'}] is just an snippet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20456/discussion-between-aamir-adnan-and-sharataka)